# Cannot change width of element

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Quick and dirty example [here](https://codepen.io/Legends/pen/dyPMaMK?editors=1100).
Just open CDT and select the a- tag.

```css
.collapsible-header {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  direction: inherit;
  visibility: visible;
  list-style-type: none;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  line-height: inherit;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  direction: inherit;
  visibility: visible;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #757575;
  font-size: 1.0769rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  height: 48px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 0px !important;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="collapsible-header" tabindex="0">
  <a class="waves-effect waves-blue">
    <i class="material-icons">folder_special</i>
    <span>Layouts</span>
    <i class="material-icons right opener" style="margin-right:0;">arrow_drop_down</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

---

I have a block-level element `a` with `display:block`.
In css I set it's `width` to `0px` but it will not change the width.

In the first picture you can see that it gets applied correctly, but the onion view still shows `260px` which in fact is the current width of `a`.

Usually you can change the `x` value in the "onion view", but in this case the change instantly reverts back to `260px`.

The `a` element has three children, two are `display:none` and the other one has a width of about 60px including padding.

So, why is that?

[image]

**"Onion view"**

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

It's not directly recognizable that the width setting does not get applied because of the `flex` setting when using Chrome Devtools.

This is better solved in FF, look here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent element has `display: flex` so it stretches the element you're looking at. It's the inherent behavior of flex layouts. You can prevent it by specifying `flex: 0` CSS on the child element (`<a>` in this case).

Comment: I didn't look at the `flex` style, because usually when you set a width for a `block-level` element and it does not get overridden by other styles, that's it, it gets applied as specified. But as you can see in my OP, the CDT don't tell you anything that the width doesn't get applied. It just says: yeah it's set to `0px` but it doesn't tell you that `flex` makes it invalid. This could be a new feature for CDT, to somehow make clear that it got invalidated by `flex` somewhere up the hierarchy.

Comment: Yeah, you can see it in the "onion view", but the `Computed tab` shows `0px`..

Comment: Firefox's devtools presents flex stuff in a much better fashion, AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah, this is absolutely better solved in FF, it even has a `Flexbox` highlighter toggle. Thanks for the hint!